# Configure Service Settings in Windows 7 programmatically using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

If you edit a service in Windows 7 and go to the Log On Tab, there is an option to "Allow service to interact with desktop". I'm trying to ensure that it is set for a certain service using VB.NET. Does anyone know of a way to do this?
Note: Doing this during the install of a program is not an option. It has to be done at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Call ChangeServiceConfig with SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681987%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). The benefit of using Windows API is that it should takes care of the notification and consurrency part and invalidate the cache in other programs that uses service controller, and when something goes wrong, you get an error code back. Generally speaking you should not access the registry if you can use API to get/set a setting.

Answer (score 1):

Service configuration is stored in the registry, under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\
```

With a key for each service.

It appears that the third to last flag within the **Type** value corresponds to the 'interact with desktop' value.

For example, a service set to NOT interact with the desktop has a value of:

```
Type    REG_DWORD   0x0000010 (16)
```

whereas that same service, when set to be allowed to interact with the desktop has a value of:

```
Type    REG_DWORD   0x0000110 (272)
```

I can't say that this is guaranteed as I've not done any testing, but it may be a good place to start.  You'd need to restart the service before the changes to this value take effect.

Comment: I would prefer not to do a registry hack for this but if it comes down to it, it would work.

Comment: It's not really a 'hack'.  The value for this configuration parameter is stored IN the registry.  You're not hacking the registry as much as you're bypassing the windows UI to configure this parameter.  In the end, it's the same thing.

Comment: Yes I know it's not a "hack" I guess I use that word to loosely but I would prefer some API or library call. I gave you the rep though. Thanks